# software to trigger and run recordings with USB soundcards

Tags: recording, experiment-design, fieldwork

I'm looking to trigger recordings as bats pass by my mic array.l, and also to potentially run playbacks too through the soundcard (it has both ADC and DAC capabilities). I have an ASIO based USB soundcard attached to my laptop, that'd I'd le to program to run.

I know SoundMexPro, a MATLAB and proprietary dongle-activated software which my colleagues have used. However I'm looking for something open-source to control the sound card, what options are available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real-time audio programming is useful in this case as you can monitor what is going on at any time. Multi-platform open-source software called [Pure Data](https://puredata.info/) allows you to visually program a threshold and to launch automatically a recording (see objects [env~] or [threshold~] to detect at a level that you can set). There is the more friendly but proprietary version called [Max](https://cycling74.com/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with coding your own solution, i highly recommend the `sounddevice` Python package. With the `Stream` class, you can initiate simultaneous playback/recording if required, and otherwise also just do only playback or recording.

I used it to trigger automated recordings once a threshold was  crossed. The code ran all through my field season with no problems at all. Alternately the `pyaudio` package is also likely to have very similar functionality.

I do know my bird song colleagues also use other software like Sound Analysis Pro, a GUI program built with many other features.